# Too many open files in Lucene Indexing when number of users increase

Tags: java, lucene

I have been using Lucene Indexing and search technique for my web application. Initially I faced the "Too many Open files problem", after research I fixed it by using a common IndexSearcher for single user. Then, when I tested the application with a greater number of concurrent users, it again started to bring "Too many Open files problem".

I am keeping the IndexSearcher Object in the session of particular user, which is always keeping a few files open(which they are currently using). Could any one please help to overcome this issue even if there is any number of users?

Let me know if I am not clear anywhere in the above explanation.

Comment: Using "Linux" in the application server

Answer (score 2):

Lucene's FAQ has a [nice entry about it](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Why_am_I_getting_an_IOException_that_says_.22Too_many_open_files.22.3F).

In a nutshell:

- Check that all your Lucene IndexReader, IndexWriter, and IndexSearcher are correctly closed
- Try to use compound files, that limits the number of files created
- Increase the limit of opened file handles on your operating system

I had similar problem with Lucene a while ago, and when you have a lot of concurrent users, this limit can easily be reached. Increasing the file handles limit worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Great clues Vivien. I hope this would work.  Still I have a question..

Previously, I was trying to keep the hits in session.  This too kept the files open and I dropped the plan.  Is there any way to keep the results(or hits) in session with out having the files open?

Comment: @user1059414 Copy the results in custom objects, so you can release the Lucene Result objects but keep the data in another form.

Comment: Thanks Vivien. Ya I tried exactly the same a while before. I created custom objects, stored the values from the Hits in to it, then packed those objects in to a single ArrayList. I started keeping this ArrayList in the session. Every thing worked fine but it all started to affect the performance.  When I took the statistics, I found, the data retrieval from the index was taking 4 secs and packing them in to a ArrayList of custom Objects took almost 12 secs...Please suggest me if I am doing the things rite

Comment: Anyone please suggest me a solution for this. :(

Comment: Why do you keep results in the session in the first place? Try to keep results in the request scope, even if that means re-executing a search query to go to the next page in search results.