# How to safely close an IndexReader?

Tags: java, lucene

My question is very simple, When use `IndexReader.openIfChanged (reader)` replace the previous `reader`, How to safely the close `oldReader`?

Here is the code: (Use Lucene 3.5)

```
IndexReader newReader=IndexReader.openIfChanged(reader);
if(newReader!=null){
    IndexReader oldReader=reader;
    IndexSearcher oldSearcher=searcher;

    reader=newReader;
    searcher=new IndexSearcher(newReader);

    oldSearcher.close();
    oldReader.close();//or oldReader.decRef(),result is the same
}
```

This code in a deamon thread,Every 5 seconds run time

`IndexReader` instance(`reader` object) is globally unique

Since this change, I get an exception:

```
org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexReader is closed
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.ensureOpen(IndexReader.java:297)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.getSequentialSubReaders(IndexReader.java:1622)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery$TermWeight.scorer(TermQuery.java:98)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:298)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:298)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:577)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:517)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:400)
    at org.zenofo.index.IndexManager.query(IndexManager.java:392)
    ...
```

`IndexManager.java:392` using the `reader` object(`IndexReader` instance,globally unique)

`IndexManager.query` method has a large number of concurrent requests, all requests to use a globally unique `IndexReader` instance (`reader` object)

[image]

I need to close `oldReader` just because:

- [Too many open files in Lucene Indexing when number of users
  increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224413/too-many-open-files-in-lucene-indexing-when-number-of-users-increase)
- [Lucene Wiki:Too many open files](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Why_am_I_getting_an_IOException_that_says_.22Too_many_open_files.22.3F)

Reference:

- [API-IndexReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/index.html?org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html)
- [API-IndexSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the reader is not closed before call to openIfChanged?

Comment: And what is your concurrency setting? If this code can be executed concurrenctly, there are many things that may be wrong with it. Anyway, you shouldn't be implementing this yourself since Lucene already [provides its own SearcherManager](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html).

Comment: @vikas My question describes the error, I have to revise and rewrite the question

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for answer,`oldReader.close()` contains a deamon thread,`IndexReader` instance is globally unique,exception occurs in the method of `IndexManager.query`,`IndexManager.query` support concurrent(Before my question to describe the error,I fixed)

Comment: But does your code get executed concurrently? If yes, what measures are you taking to ensure proper behavior?

Comment: @vikas I'm sure the reader is not closed before call to openIfChanged

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik IndexReader instances are completely thread safe, meaning multiple threads can call any of its methods http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/index.html?org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html

Comment: That's not the issue. You have a whole block of code that should execute atomically. How are you ensuring that?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean, can further explain? Thank you for answering

Comment: Did you surround the code you have pasted with a `synchronized` block? Or is it within a `synchronized` method? Anything of that kind?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Replace the Reader's code (I paste the code in the question) in a daemon thread, which guarantees the global uniqueness does not have any concurrent.
IndexManager.query method will also be multiple client calls
IndexReader are thread-safe, so no synchronization

Comment: My question is, how does the daemon thread guarantee it? How does it impose a `happens-before` relationship between its writes to `reader` and `searcher` and reads of those vars by other threads? How does it guarantee the atomicity of the two writes to `reader` and `searcher` as observed by the reading threads?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `reader` and `searcher` is a static field in project(and I drew a diagram to explain the problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AQiRT.gif)

Comment: I think you are not familiar with the Java Memory Model. Do you know what a `happens-before` relationship is?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry I didn't know what a `happens-before` relationship is, T.T ,Can I change the de deamon thread code and solve the AlreadyClosedException? help me ~

Comment: A simple way: make an object with two final fields holding the reader and the searcher. Use a `static volatile` var to point to it. On each index reopen create a new such object and put it in the var.

Comment: thanks @MarkoTopolnik ! I'll be try

Comment: Are you sure you need both the reader and the searcher var from other threads? You can get to the reader through the searcher. You wouldn't need that holder object in that case, just a volatile var pointing to the searcher.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you're right,I only need `searcher`(btw:I simplify the question:When use IndexReader.openIfChanged (reader) replace the previous reader, How to safely the close oldReader?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at NRTManager and SearcherManager. You really don't have to handle this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to impose the `happens-before` relationship between writes to the `public static` vars and subsequent reads of them from other threads. If you use more than one var, you'll have the issue of atomicity so I recommend you use only one var since that is all you need.

Simply, this would work for you:

```
public class SearcherManager 
{
  public static volatile IndexSearcher searcher;

  private static void reopen() {
    // your code, just without assignment to reader
  }
}
```

The key is the `volatile` modifier. Be sure to fully initialize everything before writing to the var, but do the closing of old objects after the write—in other words, just make sure you go on doing it the way you are doing it now :)

But, as @MJB notes in his answer, you should **really** not be doing this since it is all built into Lucene. Check out the [Javadoc on NRTManagerReopenThread](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NRTManagerReopenThread.html) to get all the info you need, including a full code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the searcher (that later refereed as oldSearcher) if working on reader (oldReader), in that case when you close it it close also the reader it use, so you don't need to close it,
oldSearcher.close() is enough.

Comment: Closing IndexSearcher does not close the underlying IndexReader unless it is using implicit reader. [Reference](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#close%28%29).

Comment: You're right, that's what I said- I assume that he build the searcher so it will use the reader implicit.

Comment: Implicit reader means when IndexSearcher is created by providing the path to directory containing indexes. So, if the oldSearcher was created using [this](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#IndexSearcher%28org.apache.lucene.store.Directory%29) constructor and reader was retrieved from it later on, it would close the underlying reader.

Comment: OK, so @Zenofo, please give us more info about how you created the searcher so we will know what use case we are facing.

Comment: @shem thanks for answer,I need to close `oldReader`(I has supplement the reasons in the qustion)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see at all what oldReader and oldSearcher are doing at all!!!!!
Can't you just remove them along with their `close()`
If you still need them, then my bet is that the oldSearcher somehow is related to oldReader, so calling `close()` on oldSearcher also causes closing oldReader that's why you get the exception
Is that the whole bulk of code, or did u simplify it? if yes to to first, then just remove oldReader and oldSearcher altogether

Cheers

Comment: thanks for answer,Before my question to describe the error,I fixed and rewrite the question

Comment: though I believe strongly that the second close() call is made on a closed stream. caused by the first close(). Try checking ifClosed() or something on oldReader, since other users have mentioned, oldReader and oldSearcher one is used to initialize the other, so closing one of them, also closes the other

Comment: I removed `oldSearcher.close()` only run `oldReader.close()` the problem is the same

Comment: good. keep it removed/commented. can you check whether oldReader is closed already, because it looks like it. Maybe reader is already closed and assigned it to oldReader then oldReader is also closed

Comment: You're right,oldSearcher.close() is not important,But the problem is oldReader.close(),and thrown exception in `IndexManager.query` method

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the indexreader reference counting methods. 
i.e Increase the reference count when you are instantiating a new IndexSearcher with
`reader.incRef();` and decrease it when you're done with the search results and preferably in a finally statement of a try catch method with `reader.decRef()`;

`reader.decRef()` automatically closes the reader when the number of references is 0.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take a look at page 361-364 of lucene in Action book